# Generate link to Liferay root site from Portlet's JSP

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am writing a Portlet, which will be placed on a given liferay site.
Liferay can have multiple sites, which can be public or private.

How can I generate a link (in my portlet JSP) to root page of the site in which the portlet was placed?
e.g. for the site `mySite` I expect something like `http://localhost:8080/web/mySite/`

Those two are not what I need:

```
themeDisplay.getPortalURL() // "liferay portal web root", not site root
themeDisplay.getURLHome() // default site home, not necessarily my specific site
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope the following meets your needs :

```
String portalPath = PortalUtil.getPortalURL(themeDisplay);

boolean isPrivateLayout = themeDisplay.getLayout().isPrivateLayout();
Group scopeGroup = themeDisplay.getScopeGroup();
String groupUrl = PortalUtil.getGroupFriendlyURL(scopeGroup,isPrivateLayout,themeDisplay);

String result = portalPath + groupUrl;
```

Best regards,
Alain

Comment: This even includes the full URL and port. Thanks Alain.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `themeDisplay.getLayout().getRegularURL(request)` or `themeDisplay.getScopeGroup().getPathFriendlyURL(false,themeDisplay)`

HTH

Comment: the first snippet is the link to the current page, the 2nd one is a link to http://localhost:8080/web/ and is missing the site context